# How to build a bitcoinj checkpoint file

Tags: bitcoinj, android, checkpoints, bitcoin-wallet-app

How can I build a bitcoinj checkpoint file
like the [Bitcoin-wallet checkpoints](https://github.com/schildbach/bitcoin-wallet/blob/master/wallet/assets/checkpoints)?

Answer (score 3):

From this discussion: [How to create a checkpoint file](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bitcoinj/CycE9YTS7Bs)

Run `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.google.bitcoin.tools.BuildCheckpoints` in the tools/ directory from the [bitcoinj repository](https://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/).

BuildCheckpoints expects you to have a fully synced local Bitcoin-Qt/bitcoind instance running.

Answer (score 0):

Providing an updated answer:
Bitcoinj provides a tool for that. I'll assume you have downloaded [bitcoinj repository](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj):

Inside the '*tools*' folder you will find a file called *build-checkpoints.cmd* (for Windows, or just build-checkpoints for Linux).

Try *build-checkpoints -help* to learn about the tool's options.

If you don't have a local bitcoin node, you should provide a node's ip using the *-peer* parameter.